# Common and visually intuitive approach for User to select items from a collection (.NET WinForms)

Tags: .net, string, winforms, filter, collections

Well, it's hard for me to find correct name of what I'm trying to do.
So I will describe the process from the user's point of view.

1. There is some collection of strings (let's say `List<string>`) - it can be huge (>=100 items).
2. User should have an option to select a `List<string>` subset from this collection. Adding and removing items from a subset should be availble. Usually subset contains about <10 items.
3. "Live search" funtionality for initial collection is also required.

I saw the same functionality in some programs, but really don't have any idea how to name that (maybe "dynamic filter" or something similar).

So for now I have two UI options:

1. `ListBox` that contains initial collection with a `TextBox` above it (for "live search"). Clicking item adds that item to subset and also adds a Label to some UI container (`Panel` maybe). Clicking X-mark on a Label removes it from UI container (and also removes item from subset):

[image]

2. `ListBox` that contains initial collection with a `TextBox` above it (for "live search"). And enother `ListBox` for a subset. Two buttons for add/remove items to/from subset.

[image]

So - which one UI layout is better for a described task?

Maybe there is an better approach or even some custom control for this purpose?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I do not get the problem. You have some collection of strings (let's say `List<string>`) which is displaying through `ComboBox` and now what you are trying to achieve is for user to be able to manipulate with each item (delete, rename, etc)?

Comment: `List<string> superset` you are talking about (binded to a `ComboBox`) is a collection from which user can select a `List<string> subset`. Click on item in `ComboBox` adds that item to **subset** and also adds a `Label` to some UI container, `Panel` maybe (see picture in my question). Click **X** on a `Label` removes it from UI container (and also removes item from **subset**). Renaming is not needeed in my case. The main problem is how to represent current state of **subset** to User in UI (I described my approach with `Label`s - but is is good or there is some control or better approach)?

Comment: What do you mean by `current state of subset`

Comment: User should see what strings are currently in that subset. I've updated my question - added another approach (currently I'm using it).

Comment: Yes, using two listboxes is a very common and intuitive approach.  CheckedListBox or a ListView with CheckBoxes = true are ways to do it that are more compact.  We can't help you choose.

Comment: @HansPassant - do you recommend me to have only one `CheckedListBox` or a `ListView` with `CheckBoxes = true`? So that User can visually determine selected items by checkbox state? Unfortunatelly it's not an option for me because entire collection of strings might be very huge (100 or even more), but User usually selects only а small subset (<10). That's why I am to have separate `ListBox` with "live search" functionality.

Comment: @bairog the question can't be answered by SO or *you*, the developer. There are *many* ways to select items. Whether they are suitable or not depends on the users and how they work though. Both options may be "best" for different scenarios, different number of items, different screens.

Comment: @bairog the users' experience matters a LOT too. Option #2 is what SharePoint used in the past. Yes, it seems OK, until you see a *new* user try to make sense of it. It's different from what people have come to expect so it takes time to become familiar. On the other hand Option #1 with a checkboxlist is more familiar for new users and occasional use but far more cumbersome if there are a lot of options to make, and the users have to use that screen multiple times per day or hour

Comment: @bairog another option seen in VS and VS code Git panels is to display the selections at the top. This works because side panels shouldn't take a lot of horizontal space and they aren't used as heavily as the main editor pane. You could do the same with a CheckListBox or ListView, by ordering the items based on their selection flag. That probably won't work with 10 selections though.

Comment: This is too much opinion based...